# Outward flux of a vector field through the intersection of two cylinders.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, divergence-operator, cylindrical-coordinates

**Exercise**

Consider the region
$$
D=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\, x^2+y^2\leq9, y^2+z^2\leq25\}.
$$

**1.** Write down a parametrization of the boundary $∂D$ of $D$.

**2.** Compute the outward pointing unit normal field **n** of the boundary $∂D$.

**3.** Compute the outward flux of the vector field
$$
F(x,y,z)=\Big(x\sqrt{25-y^2},\,\,x\sqrt{25-z^2},\,\,y\sqrt{9-x^2}\Big)
$$
through the closed surface $∂D$.

**Solution.**

**1.**
The region $D$ consists of that portion of a "vertical" cylinder (whose axis coincides with the $z$ axis) which is contained into another "horizontal" cylinder (whose axis coincides with the $x$ axis). We can split the boundary $∂D$ of $D$ into three parts, and provide three different parametrizations:
$$
\mathbb{R}^2\supseteq\{u^2+v^2\leq9\}\ni(u, v)\longmapsto\Big(u, v, \sqrt{25-v^2}\Big)
$$
for the upper "cover";
$$
\mathbb{R}^2\supseteq\{u^2+v^2\leq9\}\ni(u, v)\longmapsto\Big(u, v, -\sqrt{25-v^2}\Big)
$$
for the lower "cover"; 
$$
\mathbb{R}^2\supseteq\{0\leq\theta\leq2\pi,\,\,9\sin^2(\theta)+z^2\leq25\}\ni(\theta, z)\longmapsto\Big(3\cos(\theta),\,\,3\sin(\theta),\,\, z\Big)
$$
for the side (using cylindrical coordinates).

**2.**
It is easy to see that we have:
$$
n_1=\Big(0, \frac{v}{\sqrt{25-v^2}}, 1\Big)
$$

$$
n_1=\Big(0, -\frac{v}{\sqrt{25-v^2}}, 1\Big)
$$

$$
n_3=(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta), 0).
$$
I am struggling with computing the outward flux of the vector field $F$. I tried both using the definition of outward flux of a vector field through a surface and using the divergence theorem and cylindrical coordinates (which quite looks as the right way to approach this third question, as the divergence of the vector field $F$ is quite simple). Nevertheless, I cannot get anywhere. 
Can anybody provide some help?

Comment: have you tried computing dot product of normal vector and field on the boundary surface $\hat{n}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{F}$ then integrate over each surface

Comment: also, have you normalized the normal vectors ... given that one of the components has value unity leads me to believe that you have not?